# aiohttp Clientsession post stuck

Tags: post, timeout, aiohttp

I try to get some information from Quora using a python web crawler program written by aiohttp. I used `aiohttp.ClientSession` to build a connect session and set the timeout `aiohttp.ClientTimeout(total=5)`. Most of the time, my program was fine, but sometimes it would be stuck e.g. I tried to use `aiohttp.ClientSession.post` to fetch some data from https://www.quora.com/graphql/gql_para_POST?q=EditCredentialsModalQuery and check the **response status**. It stuck at this step. The `aiohttp.ClientTimeout(total=5)` seems invalid. Here is my code and bug picture:

```
        async with semaphore:
            while req_time <= 3:
                try:
                    async with session.post(url='https://www.quora.com/graphql/gql_para_POST?q'
                                                '=EditCredentialsModalQuery',
                                            headers=headers, data=payload, proxy=self.proxy) as resp:
                        if resp.status != 200:
                            print(f'{user_name}[ModalQuery]: resp.status is not 200, retrying {req_time}\n')
                            await asyncio.sleep(2)
                            req_time += 1
                            continue
                except Exception as e:
                    print(f'{user_name}[ModalQuery]: Async func get_cred_from_EditCredentialsModalQuery Error: {e}, '
                          f'retrying {req_time}')
                    await asyncio.sleep(2)
                    req_time += 1
                    continue
```

[get_stuck_img](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3hWR3.png)